# Springboot maven jetty version cannot be changed

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jetty, embedded-jetty

My JDK is:

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
Chethans-Macbook-Pro-2:viglink chethanshankar$
```

My maven version is:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T08:41:47-08:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

I want to change my spring-boot's Jetty version to: **8.1.15.v20140411**

I have the following in my pom:

```
<properties>
    <jetty.version>8.1.15.v20140411</jetty.version>
    <jetty-jsp.version>2.2.0.v201112011158</jetty-jsp.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

The "mvn dependency:tree" and "mvn clean install" compiles to:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO] |  |           +- (javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |           +- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |           \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.3.11.v20160721:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

My main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {        
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class,
                SpringComponentScanConfiguration.class,
                CommonDataLayerConfigurer.class,
                CommonSchedulingConfigurer.class,
                CommonSpringContextConfiguration.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.CONSOLE);
        app.run( args);

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do i change the Jetty version in my pom? Thanks.

Comment: why do you need to change the Jetty version ? any issues ?

Comment: [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html)

Comment: Considering that Jetty 9.3.11 has a Java 8 minimum requirement, that would also likely mean spring-boot 1.4.1.RELEASE has a Java 8 minimum requirement.  The spring-boot for jetty 9.3 would also be incompatible with Jetty 8.1 (that's 4 major versions of Jetty and about 300 releases in difference)

Comment: @javaguy We are currently on JDK 1.7 hence want to use a spring-boot Jetty version (without inheriting from parent spring boot) which is compatible with JDK 1.7.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt How do i use Spring-boot Jetty without inheriting from parent while on JDK 1.7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the property override to work, you need to declare spring-boot-starter-parent as your parent pom.

## (1) Without `spring-boot` as parent - Jetty v9.2.9.v20150224

If you don't wish to use `spring-boot` as your parent pom (as you said in the comments), you need to :

- exclude `jetty-servlets` from `spring-boot-starter-jetty`
- include `jetty-servlets` yourself with the targeted version.

Example, based on the `dependency:tree` you provided:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.package.groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>appname</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <jetty.version>9.2.9.v20150224</jetty.version>
        <servlet-api.version>3.1.0</servlet-api.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-continuation</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-deploy</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-jmx</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-security</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax-websocket-server-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.alexbt.Launcher</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

## (2) Without spring-boot as parent - jetty v8.1.15.v20140411

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.package.groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>appname</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.15.v20140411</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.alexbt.Launcher</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

## (3) Example with `spring-boot` as parent

Use the following (taken from [Spring-Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <jetty.version>8.1.15.v20140411</jetty.version>
        <jetty-jsp.version>2.2.0.v201112011158</jetty-jsp.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Package as an executable jar -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### Jetty 9.2

By the way, Jetty version 9.2 is compatible with JDK 7 ([see table here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_servlet_containers)).

Comment: Do you have an pom.xml example in which Jetty version is overridden when spring-boot is not inherited as parent?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example, based on the mvn dependency:tree you provided

Comment: Tnx @Alex. I used your changes and see the following error , am I doing something wrong in my main class?

Comment: 2016-11-01 16:38:56.460  WARN 83615 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
2016-11-01 16:38:56.469 ERROR 83615 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

Comment: You are right I had the same error. I updated the pom with many dependencies (copied from spring-boot and changed the version). I was able to make it work with jetty 9.2, but no luck with 8.1.15. Not saying it isnt possible, I'm sure it is, but first just how much is it a hard requirement to use jetty 8.1.15 ?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a working pom for jetty v9.3xx and another one for jetty v8.15xxx. Let me know.

Comment: Tnx Alex. Your exclusion/inclusion pom.xml worked for me. Pls see my answer for the complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. I got spring-boot without parent working with Jetty with the following:

```
    <jetty.version>9.2.17.v20160517</jetty.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
```

The key is to:

1. **Exclude** spring-boot Tomcat and **include** spring-boot jetty jars.
2. **AND** Include all of the spring-boot Jetty jars.(cannot stress this enough)

Spring Boot Documentation is slightly misleading as it doesn't specify that you have to include all of the individual tomcat/jetty jars when you don't inherit from spring-boot parent.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent

I am attaching the entire pom.xml and you can omit the dependencies related to "companyABC". Hope it is useful to someone else.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.companyABC</groupId>
        <artifactId>companyABC-parent-account</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.10-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../companyABC-parent/account/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.companyABC</groupId>
    <artifactId>companyABC-campaign-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <jetty.version>9.2.17.v20160517</jetty.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
        <snippetsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-snippets</snippetsDirectory>
        <!-- TODO ? set this with an environmental variable -->
        <springboot.root>/mnt/persistent/springboot</springboot.root>
        <springboot.version>1.4.0.RELEASE</springboot.version>

        <companyABC.test.version>1.1.0</companyABC.test.version>
        <companyABC.core.version>1.1.27</companyABC.core.version>
        <companyABC.account.version>1.1.10</companyABC.account.version>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release-mode</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- dont skip test to have the doc created -->
                            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Documentation.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <companyABC_env>test</companyABC_env>
                                <spring.profiles.active>test</spring.profiles.active>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                            <!-- <argLine>${surefire.default.argLine}</argLine> 
                                <forkCount>1</forkCount> <reuseForks>true</reuseForks> -->
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!--TODO swap parent above with this block below (wasn't working 
            earlier) -->
        <!--<dependency> -->
        <!--&lt;!&ndash; Import dependency management from Spring Boot &ndash;&gt; -->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId> -->
        <!--<version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version> -->
        <!--<type>pom</type> -->
        <!--<scope>import</scope> -->
        <!--</dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-continuation</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-xml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-security</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-jndi</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
                    <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
                    <artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax-websocket-server-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-continuation</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-http</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-io</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-security</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax-websocket-server-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.companyABC</groupId>
            <artifactId>companyABC-email</artifactId>
            <version>${companyABC.account.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.companyABC</groupId>
            <artifactId>companyABC-user</artifactId>
            <version>${companyABC.account.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.companyABC</groupId>
            <artifactId>companyABC-common</artifactId>
            <version>${companyABC.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.companyABC</groupId>
            <artifactId>companyABC-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${companyABC.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--TODO figure out if there's a better way of handling this? -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- needed for hibernate for some reason -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TODO figure out why this isn't imported automatically (is a 
            dependency of companyABC-fulltextsearch -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId> <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId> 
            <version>2.3.4</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.companyABC</groupId>
            <artifactId>companyABC-test</artifactId>
            <version>${companyABC.test.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.companyABC</groupId>
            <artifactId>companyABC-common</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>${companyABC.core.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Test deps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-restassured</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <!-- Add support for the "deb" packaging -->
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.vafer</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdeb</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>

        <plugins>
            <!--Allows packaging of artifact as executable jar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <maxmem>1024m</maxmem>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Standard restdocs config -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Documentation.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>book</doctype>
                            <attributes>
                                <snippets>${snippetsDirectory}</snippets>
                            </attributes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.outputDirectory}/static/docs
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>
                                        ${project.build.directory}/generated-docs
                                    </directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Debian packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>jdeb</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.vafer</groupId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <controlDir>[[baseDir]]/src/config/deb</controlDir>
                    <classifier>all</classifier>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jdeb</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <controlDir>${basedir}/src/deb/control</controlDir>
                            <dataSet>
                                <data>
                                    <src>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</src>
                                    <type>file</type>
                                    <mapper>
                                        <type>perm</type>
                                        <prefix>${springboot.root}/campaign</prefix>
                                        <filemode>644</filemode>
                                        <user>root</user>
                                        <group>root</group>
                                    </mapper>
                                </data>
                            </dataSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- These probably need to be refactored -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <allowTimestampedSnapshots>true</allowTimestampedSnapshots>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                    <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
                    <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
                    <arguments>-DskipTests=true -P release-mode,prod</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>companyABC-repo</id>
            <url>http://nexus/content/groups/public</url>
            <snapshots>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>companyABC-repo</id>
            <url>http://nexus/content/groups/public</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <!-- use the following if you're not using a snapshot version. -->
        <repository>
            <id>companyABC-nexus</id>
            <name>RepositoryProxy</name>
            <url>http://nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>

        <!-- use the following if you ARE using a snapshot version. -->
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>companyABC-nexus</id>
            <name>RepositoryProxy</name>
            <url>http://nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:companyABC/companyABC.git</connection>
        <url>scm:git:git@github.com:companyABC/companyABC.git</url>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:companyABC/companyABC.git</developerConnection>
        <tag>companyABC-campaign-1.0.0</tag>
    </scm>
</project>
```